# How to change multiple UIButton colors with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a number of buttons used and I want an efficient way of changing all it's background color instead of changing it one by one or doing it on the AppDelegate.

I basically want to avoid this

```
  buttonOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor];
  buttonTwo.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor];
  buttonThree.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor];
  buttonFour.backgroundColor = [UIColor BlueColor];
```

What's an efficient way of doing this without doing it in the AppDelegate.

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. If there is a real performance problem then profile to find out exactly where and fix. Instead concentrate on clear and understandable code. But yes, the AppDelegate is not the place for GUI code, that should be in a view controller.

Comment: you should follow this tutorial http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/03/28/interface-builder-outlet-collections.html

Comment: If these buttons are in a view controller, set them in its viewDidLoad instead of AppDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
NSArray *buttons = @[buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour];
for(UIButton *button in buttons) {
   button. backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Or, a cooler way, using KVC:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour];
[buttons setValue:[UIColor blueColor] forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
```

Comment: How is that more efficient? Not that it is not a nice solution. But for efficiency and nice solution factor `[UIColor BlueColor]` out of the loop.

Comment: It's not more efficient performance-wise, the advantage would be that you don't repeat the same line over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this , You can change the appearance proxy of Control.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Write this in Appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Hope this helps .

Thanks.

Comment: That is if I want it to be set as a default or permanently set the color but instead because I want my buttons to change in different colors in a certain condition, it has to be in a ViewController. But I appreciate the suggestion though!

Comment: Thanks @ Cyril Ivar Garcia

Answer (score 2):

If all your buttons are subviews of the same view and you wish to change all of the buttons in that subview, you could do something like the following:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        ((UIButton*)view).backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

As another option (especially useful if you don't wish to change all the buttons in the given view), is to set the same tag to each of your buttons, then change the background color of a subview if it has that certain tag:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.tag == 1000) {
        ((UIButton*)view).backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you could set each button to have a unique tag in contiguous numerical order then loop through each one like so:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i ++) { // <-- Changing buttons with tags 1 - 10
    ((UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i]).backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: I like the answer except for `isKindOfClass`. That can be eliminated if all the buttons can by put in a view with  nothing else in that view.  If that can't be done another option would be to use the same tag for all the buttons.

Comment: @Zaph I can add tags as a second option, but if *all* the buttons in a view are being changed, isKindOfClass may require substantially less effort to implement since you can forgo setting tags for a potentially large number of buttons.