# Change Background Color of multiple UIButton in Single Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibutton

I have 16 `UIButton` in a `UIViewController` and only one need to be `selected` at a time.

I have created a `UIButton` collection and changing `backgroundColor` by performing the `for loop`. It's working fine.

But I need a quick solution in one / two line or I can say the efficient way to change color in a single click.

I don't think my way is efficient because what if the `UIViewController` has 50 `UIButton`.

P.S. Don't tell me to take `UICollectionView` as I can easily do with that!

Comment: see this once you get idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208045/how-to-change-multiple-uibutton-colors-with-objective-c

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Already seen, it's also performing loop and I think `KVC` is also not perfect solution. I want to do it without going over the loop.

Comment: You can actually drag and drop your button into an array of button from storyboard, then you can do a loop for each button in there to change

Comment: @Tj3n Yes already doing that, but looking for different solution.

Comment: I think whatever other way its also needed a loop...since each button is separate variable...even with KVO and singleton manager also needed loop

Answer (score 1):

You will anyway need enumerate your buttons. But you can do this once in extension:

```
extension Array where Element: UIButton {
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        for element in self {
            element.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that! But I need to do it without a loop because if I have higher number of buttons then this is not a worth solution.